# Optimize inserting std::uint32_t's into a std::vector<char>

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to insert an array of unsigned ints into a std::vector.

Here is my current code:

```
auto add_chars(std::vector<char> & vec, unsigned val[]){
    std::string tmp;
    tmp.resize(11) // Max chars a uint can be represented by, including the '\n' for sprintf
    for (auto x = 0; x< 10; x++){
        auto char_count = sprintf(tmp.data(),"%u", val[x]);
        vec.insert(vec.begin()+vec.size(),tmp.data(), tmp.data()+char_count);
    }

}

int main(){
    std::vector<char> chars;
    unsigned val[10] {1,200,3,4,5,6000,7,8,9000};
    add_chars(chars,val);
    for (auto & item : chars){
        std::cout << item;
    }
}
```

This solution works, however I question its efficiency (and elegance).

Two questions:

- Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?
- Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

*edit Fixed a bug in the code made while transferring over to here.

Also, i'm aware that '9000' can't be represented as 1 char, whats why im using the buffer and sprintf to generate multiple chars for the one uint.

Comment: 'This works'. Not really, you are writing to a zero length string. `sprintf` doesn't resize the string to fit the characters you are putting in it. I guess it's only working in practise because the common implementation technique of *short string optimization* means you have a few bytes to play with in the string object itself.

Comment: What's the point in inserting an array of ints in a vector of chars?

Comment: `tmp.data()` is read only. No?

Comment: if its about the data you can do this ``char* data = (char*)val;`` and avoid sprintf

Comment: A few people seem to be missing that the OP is trying to convert the integers to character digits. It's not the bytes that are being inserted to the vector but the (ASCII) digits.

Comment: Hm, but what do you expect when trying to convert `9000` to a char?

Comment: @vahancho I think four chars, `"9000"`. That's what the code nearly does.

Comment: @vahancho `tmp.data()` is writable in C++17

Comment: Strictly speaking [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) should be the fastest conversion to local invariant representation. That said you will need to allocate buffer for that.

Comment: @john Yeah you're right, forgot to init the size of the string in the code I posted here.

Comment: @Narase No, this is a lexical conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

A character stream is idiomatic for this. Unfortunately, the standard only has a stream for building a string; not a vector. You can copy the string into a vector though. This is not most efficient way:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
unsigned val[10] {1,200,3,4,5,6000,7,8,9000};
for (auto v : val)
    ss << v;
std::string str = ss.str();

// if you need a vector for some reason
std::vector<char> chars(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
```

Or you could write your own custom vector stream, but that will be a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: I like this solution, I don't strictly need to use vectors, they are just quicker to std::move() than strings due to SSO.

Comment: @vddox I'd profile before assuming, most strings move extremely quick even with SSO.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a couple of changes (and fix the bug).

Firstly the number of digits in an integer is limited so there's no need to use a dynamic object like `std::string`, a simple char array will do. Since you are using `uint32_t` and decimal digits 10 characters are sufficient, 11 if you include a nul terminator.

Secondly `sprintf` and similar are inefficient because they have to interpret the format string, `"%u"` in your case. A hand written function to perform the conversion from `uint32_t` to digits would be more efficient.

Comment: Or they could just use [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars)

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, didn't know about that one.